# Why BigQuery cannot recognize the right order for the text formatted time duration

Tags: google-bigquery

For my dataset, I would like to solve a very easy problem. I'd like to count the distinct employee ids by time durations. In my dataset, the time duration is as below:
0-6
6-12
12-18
18-24
24-

Actually, the solution is pretty simple

```
SELECT
  tenure_group, count (distinct EmpID )as count
FROM
  `T1`
group by time_group
order by time_group ascending

However, the result turns out to be 
Row     time_group      count   
1       null              0
2       0-6              501
3       12-18            183
4       18-24            229
5       24-32            238
6       32-48            438
7       48-              282
8       6-12             353
```

Seems that 6-12 is always regarded as the last group. I also tried it in Google Data Studio, but the same result.

Can anyone help? I had been thinking about its original data formatting in Google Sheets. But later, I have already changed them into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  tenure_group, count (distinct EmpID )as count
FROM
  `T1`
group by time_group
order by 
CASE 
  WHEN time_group = '6-12' THEN '06-12'
  ELSE time_group 
END asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The time_group field appears to be a string. Because they are strings, they are sorted alphanumerically.  To get it to sort 'numerically', you'd need to change '6-12' to '06-12'.